# How to join discord server using a token and a link?

Tags: python, python-requests, discord, token

I understand that it used to be possible to join the discord server using a token via python requests, but judging by the video I found, this method no longer works...Is there anything else on this topic?

The code I made using a YouTube video

```
import requests


token_list = ["12345", "1233456", etc.]


def join(server_invite):
    while True:
        for item in range(len(token_list)):
            header = {
                "authorization": token_list[item]
            }
            r = requests.post("https://discord.com/api/v9/invites/{}".format(server_invite), headers=header)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    join("Server invite code")
```